# How to access a String inside a different function

Tags: javascript

I want to access `entityString` value in `updateMarkerIcon` function in below code. `entityString` has the below attributes from which I want to access Status value in `updateMarkerIcon` function.

id: Building No. 3
type: MetroStation
Address: Kashmiri_GateMetro
Latitud: 28.6674
Longitud: 77.2282
No. Of Rooms: 6
State: Critical
Status: Temperature is high --

```
function() {

  "use strict";

  var icon;

  MashupPlatform.wiring.registerCallback("entityInput", function(entityString) {
    var entity = JSON.parse(entityString);
    var coordinates = null;
    var coord_parts = null;
    var coordinates_pref = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('coordinates_attr');
    var attributes = coordinates_pref.split(new RegExp(',\\s*'));
    if (attributes.length < 1) {
      return;
    } else if (attributes.length >= 2 && entity[attributes[0]] != null && entity[attributes[1]] != null) {
      coord_parts = [
        entity[attributes[0]],
        entity[attributes[1]]
      ];
    } else if (entity[attributes[0]]) {
      coord_parts = entity[attributes[0]].split(new RegExp(',\\s*'));
    }

    if (coord_parts != null && coord_parts.length === 2) {
      coordinates = {
        system: "WGS84",
        lat: parseFloat(coord_parts[0]),
        lng: parseFloat(coord_parts[1])
      };
    }

    if (coordinates) {
      MashupPlatform.wiring.pushEvent("poiOutput", JSON.stringify(entity2poi(entity, coordinates)));
    }

  });

  var entity2poi = function entity2poi(entity, coordinates) {
    var poi = {
      id: entity.id,
      icon: icon,
      tooltip: entity.id,
      data: entity,
      infoWindow: buildInfoWindow.call(this, entity),
      currentLocation: coordinates
    };

    return poi;
  };

  var internalUrl = function internalUrl(data) {
    var url = document.createElement("a");
    url.setAttribute('href', data);
    return url.href;
  };
  var buildInfoWindow = function buildInfoWindow(entity) {
    var infoWindow = "<div>";
    for (var attr in entity) {
      infoWindow += '<span style="font-size:12px;"><b>' + attr + ": </b> " + entity[attr] + "</span><br />";
    }
    infoWindow += "</div>";

    return infoWindow;
  };
  var updateMarkerIcon = function updateMarkerIcon() {
    icon = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('marker-icon');
    if (icon == '') {
      icon = internalUrl('images/icon.png');
    }
  };
  MashupPlatform.prefs.registerCallback(updateMarkerIcon);
  // Init initial marker icon
  updateMarkerIcon();

}
```

Comment: I see the conditional for determining a blank icon, but otherwise what're you trying to get? Will you be sending an icon value elsewhere, and if so include that code as well.

Comment: I have 3 different icons like icon1,icon2 & icon3. So I want to print icon1 for State critical and icon2 for State Normal and icon3 for high.

Comment: I don't really have time to answer with your code, but if you look at my project you might find some inspiration for an easy solution using ```switch```. Look at lines 69-98 at https://github.com/CodeSpent/dsg-heatmap/blob/master/src/js/map.js

Answer (score 0):

Call `updateMarkerIcon()` inside of register callback and pass `entityString` to it as a variable.

Comment: I have got an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: entityString is not defined when doing this: MashupPlatform.prefs.registerCallback(updateMarkerIcon(entityString));

Comment: Call it in registerCallback on the line after `var entity = JSON.parse(entityString);` You may want to call it with the parsed value and move the `updateMarkerIcon` definition above `registerCallback`

Comment: You can find my changed code at scribd.com/document/389697137/new-18. Can you upload a link using Scribd where you can change the code and give me the link? So that I got what actually you trying to say?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change your `updateMarkerIcon()` function to accept an argument `e.g. var updateMarkerIcon = function updateMarkerIcon(<someParameterHere>)` then call that function inside of your `.registerCallback()` callback function, passing `entityString` into it `e.g. updateMarkerIcon(entityString)`

Comment: You can find my changed code at https://www.scribd.com/document/389697137/new-18. Can you tell me how to call inside a .registerCalback() function.Please upload the changes and give me the link. I will be helpful to me.